# Send List items using JQuery Post to ASP.NET Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following JQuery code in my .cshtml file.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlPath,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ pendingList: pendingList })
            }).error(function (err) {
                alert("Error " + err.status);
            });
```

The pendingList object populates with correct values.I could see the values in the post request.

[Request Data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5NTs.png)

My ASP.NET Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateMultiRequest(List[] pendingList)
        {
```

But I see null for the pendingList.Any help appreciated.

Comment: In Controller, try  change List[] pendingList to List<pendingList> pendingList

Answer (score 0):

You're posting JSON that looks like:

```json
"pendingList": {
    //...
}
```

Thus, .Net is trying to bind the posted data to an object shaped like:

```cs
class SomeType
{
    public List[] SomeOtherType { get; set; }
}
```

Instead, just call `JSON.stringify(pendingList)` which will send:

```json
{
    //...
}
```

You don't need to send a named object to the ASP .Net controller. It already expects the format of the object to match the type of parameter in the controller method.

Comment: No luck, I see the same post data value without pendingList object,

Comment: Try changing `List[]` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<List>` as Nhien mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this.
One:
Just like suggested in other answers use a generic list of type

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CreateMultiRequest(List<PnedingList> pendingList)
```

Two:
Use `FromBody` attribute to help the runtime to retrieve the object from request body

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CreateMultiRequest([FromBody]List[] pendingList)
```